# update field with existing field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

mongodb structure is like;

```
[
    {id: "1" , name: "alex"},
    {id: "2" , name: "felix"},
    {id: "3" , name: "kelix"},
    {id: "4" , name: "hannah"}
]
```

Let's assume I want to add "s" each document in the document.

```
[
    {id: "1" , name: "alexs"},
    {id: "2" , name: "felixs"},
    {id: "3" , name: "kelixs"},
    {id: "4" , name: "hannahs"}
]


db.list.updateMany({}, { $set: {name: "$name" + "s"})}
```

But this followed by `script contains errors.`

Is it possible to update field with its existing value in mongodb?